# Getting data from json array mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mariadb, mariadb-10.3

Below is my `json` data which is saved in `cold_storage_data` column of `inventory` table

```json
[{
    "qty_in_storage": "10",
    "cold_storage_id": "2",
    "cold_storage_lot_number": "678678"
}, {
    "qty_in_storage": "15",
    "cold_storage_id": "1",
    "cold_storage_lot_number": "678679"
}]
```

Now I want to retrieve the data based on the `cold_storage_lot_number`. So I have tried below solutions but none of them are working for me

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    test.inventories
WHERE
    JSON_EXTRACT( cold_storage_data, "$.cold_storage_lot_number" ) = "678679";
```

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    test.inventories
WHERE
    json_contains( cold_storage_data, "678679", "$.cold_storage_lot_number" );
```

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    test.inventories
WHERE
    cold_storage_data->"$.cold_storage_lot_number" = "678679";
```

Where I am going wrong?

The query provided by @dai [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vmkB7bZdTCV55ExL7aq68u/1) working fine with `mysql version 8` when I am testing it with `MariaDB version 10.3.35` it is not working.
[MariaDB dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YC_E31oM)

Comment: Is there a reason your data isn't normalized?

Comment: I have to keep in on table

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Mysql Version 8

Comment: To confirm, the `cold_storage_data` column in a single row contains a JSON array with multiple `object` values? Please post a DBFiddle/SQLFiddle with exemplary test data.

Comment: Ok, let me create a demo

Comment: @Dai https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vmkB7bZdTCV55ExL7aq68u/0

Comment: See the second query here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vmkB7bZdTCV55ExL7aq68u/1

Comment: Working, Thanks. Can you please tell why these basic function of `json` was not working. While it is a valid `json`

Comment: Part of the problem is that your "root" JSON value is an array `[]`, not an `object`-literal.

Comment: Ok, So the data should be in `{
 "data": [{
  "qty_in_storage": "10",
  "cold_storage_id": "2",
  "cold_storage_lot_number": "678678"
 }, {
  "qty_in_storage": "15",
  "cold_storage_id": "1",
  "cold_storage_lot_number": "678679"
 }]
}` format?

Comment: ...you should just normalize your table instead of storing JSON inline: it's a massive anti-pattern that will wreck performance.

Comment: The staging server have mariadb version 10.3 on which this query is not working. https://dbfiddle.uk/7tzTZfDj